# Traverse an array of divs by clicking

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have a page with 'previous' and 'next' buttons to traverse an array of divs.

Clicking next button will copy the next div indexed by the var 'click' into #place's innerHTML.

Clicking previous button will copy the previous div as you can imagine.

The problem is, when I click the button alternately(click previous and next and previous then next...), the div would remain as it is and will not change to the next or previous div, unless I click the same button twice.

A simple alert message would confirm the functions are executing when alternately clicked. What's going on? Thank you.

```js
var clicks = 0;
var pageDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("plist");
var displayPanel = document.getElementById("place");

function g() {
  if (clicks >= pageDivs.length) {
    clicks = 0;
  }
  displayPanel.innerHTML = pageDivs[clicks].innerHTML;

  clicks += 1;
}

function f() {
  clicks -= 1;

  if (clicks < 0) {
    clicks = pageDivs.length - 1;
  }

  displayPanel.innerHTML = pageDivs[clicks].innerHTML;

}
```

```css
.plist {
  display: none;
}

#place {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  min-height: 5%;
  min-width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="place">
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 1</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 2</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 3</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 4</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 5</p>
</div>


<button type="button" onclick="f()" style="width: 10%;">Previous</button>
<button type="button" onclick="g()" style="width: 10%;">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click `Next`, increment your counter first. You're doing it after, which is causing the issue.

Define your function `f` like this:

```
    function g() {
       clicks += 1; // increment at the start
      ...
    }
```

```js
var clicks = 0;
var pageDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("plist");
var displayPanel = document.getElementById("place");

function g() {
  clicks += 1;
  if (clicks >= pageDivs.length) {
    clicks = 0;
  }
  displayPanel.innerHTML = pageDivs[clicks].innerHTML;
}

function f() {
  clicks -= 1;

  if (clicks < 0) {
    clicks = pageDivs.length - 1;
  }

  displayPanel.innerHTML = pageDivs[clicks].innerHTML;

}
```

```css
.plist {
  display: none;
}

#place {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  min-height: 5%;
  min-width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="place">
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 1</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 2</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 3</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 4</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 5</p>
</div>


<button type="button" onclick="f()" style="width: 10%;">Previous</button>
<button type="button" onclick="g()" style="width: 10%;">Next</button>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry, was editing that in. Left it out on accident.

Comment: @mplungjan I agree. Sadly, I do not have that privilege yet.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Out of curiosity, why would increment/decrement it later creates problem? I did initialize the counter to 0 and wrote conditions so that the index would be valid index. So why wouldn't it just display the indexed div?

Comment: It won't create a problem if you increment them both later.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consistently add and subtract in the same place.

But no need for two functions

NOTE: for an additional improvement, just hide and show instead of inserting code into the DOM

```js
var clicks = -1, // necessary for initial next clicking
    pageDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("plist"),
    displayPanel = document.getElementById("place"),
    len = pageDivs.length;

function copyIt(direction) {
  clicks += direction;
  if (clicks >= len) clicks = 0;
  else if (clicks < 0) clicks = len - 1;
  displayPanel.innerHTML = pageDivs[clicks].innerHTML;
}
```

```css
.plist {
  display: none;
}

#place {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  min-height: 5%;
  min-width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="place">
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 1</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 2</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 3</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 4</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 5</p>
</div>


<button type="button" onclick="copyIt(-1)" style="width: 10%;">Previous</button>
<button type="button" onclick="copyIt(1)" style="width: 10%;">Next</button>
```

Comment: Not sure how much difference it will make, but I had this in my attempt. Instead of `clicks += direction;
  if (clicks >= len) clicks = 0;`, try `clicks = (clicks + direction) % len`. This way, you can get rid of `if` condition. That `else if` is still required though. Also, `<p>` inside `.place` is not required as OP is replacing it using `.innerHTML`

Comment: Please initialize `click = -1`, other wise clicking next for the first time will making the code to jump to 2nd index of array.

Comment: @Rajesh - having the `if` is in my mind MUCH more readable. The `<p>` is irrelevant. It could contain some initial message

Comment: This solution is more elegant. Thank you.

Comment: I had to choose only one, @mplungjan. The other solution is closer to my original code and the correction is simpler. It resonates well to my simple mind.

Comment: @ErzamMarlisah fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `clicks` counter was getting updated after updating the innerHTML.

Moving that to top fixed the issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var clicks = -1;
  var pageDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("plist");
  var displayPanel = document.getElementById("place");
  $("#prev").on("click", f);
  $("#next").on("click", g);

  function g() {
    clicks += 1;
    if (clicks >= pageDivs.length) {
      clicks = 0;
    }

    displayPanel.innerHTML = pageDivs[clicks].innerHTML;
  }

  function f() {
    clicks -= 1;
    if (clicks < 0) {
      clicks = pageDivs.length - 1;
    }
    displayPanel.innerHTML = pageDivs[clicks].innerHTML;

  }
});
```

```css
.plist {
  display: none;
}

#place {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  min-height: 5%;
  min-width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="place">
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 1</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 2</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 3</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 4</p>
</div>

<div class="plist">
  <p>Testing 5</p>
</div>


<button id="prev" type="button" style="width: 10%;">Previous</button>
<button id="next" type="button" style="width: 10%;">Next</button>
```